# can't check scala version in sbt:bin after installing sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

i installed scala using sbt. I have adoptOpenjdk java 8 distribution.

when i navigate to scala/bin folder and launch scala.bat file - i have this:

```
C:\scala\bin>sbt.bat
[warn] Neither build.sbt nor a 'project' directory in the current directory: "C:\scala\bin"
c) continue
q) quit
?c
[warn] No sbt.version set in project/build.properties, base directory: C:\scala\bin
[info] welcome to sbt 1.3.13 (AdoptOpenJDK Java 1.8.0_252)
[info] set current project to bin (in build file:/C:/scala/bin/)
[info] sbt server started at local:sbt-server-238ff4d6ac394d9cc1de
```

when trying to check scala version using

"scala -version;" or "scala-version;" i get this error:

```
sbt:bin> scala -version;
[error] Expected ';'
[error] scala -version
[error]               ^
sbt:bin>
```

what's wrong? how do i see what scala version i m running?

Comment: How did you install **Scala** using **SBT**?

Answer (score 4):

Because the particular version of Scala to use with SBT is set per-project, the scala version in use is set by the `scalaVersion` property (usually set in `build.sbt`).  It can be inspected with

```
show scalaVersion
```

at an sbt prompt.

Comment: Should add that SBT itself is implemented in scala 2.12, but since it's distributed as a binary which includes the Scala standard library etc., that really only matters if you're developing an SBT plugin.